# json object em array esta com erro java

Tags: java, json

Tenho um WebService Rest com duas classes: `Pedido` e `itensPedido`.

Na `pedido` o *insert* funciona, mas quando vai para a `itensPedido` que eu uso um Array JSON com vários itens retorna o erro:

> Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path.

Faço assim:
Abro o *postman*, gero o Array JSON pelo método *post* e envio. Aí que retorna o erro.

Alguém pode me orientar?

Meu código:

```
@POST
@Path("salvaritenspedido")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public String salvarItensPedido(String itensPedido){
    ItensPedido ip1 = g.fromJson(itensPedido, ItensPedido.class);
    ItensPedido ip2 = new ItensPedidoDao().getItensPedidos(ip1.getIdPedido(), ip1.getIdVendedor(), ip1.getIdCliente(), ip1.getIdProduto());
        if(ip2 == null){
            System.out.println("SALVAR");
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ip1));

        } else {
            System.out.println("ATUALIZAR");
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ip1));

        }
        return itensPedido;
}
```

Comment: O que a mensagem diz é . " Esperava o caractere **{** que representa um único objeto no JSON mas encontrou **[** que representa um **Array JSON**. Adicione se puder o seu JSON também. É como se estivesse transformando um Array de ItensPedido em um único objeto de ItensPedido

Comment: @lazarojvt, posta o conteúdo da string no parâmetro "itensPedido" junto com a pergunta.

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 0):

Se você está recebendo um `array` (`[]`) você deve transformar em uma lista:

```
Type tipo = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ItensPedido>>(){}.getType();
List<ItensPedido> lista = (new Gson()).fromJson(jsonArray, tipo);
```